# Use XML Web part in PnP provisioning template

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I exported an xml viewer web part with Get-PnPWebPartXml and expected that I could copy-paste this to a pnp provisioning template. Looks like that the schema is different and instead of this (example when I export a list view):

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Default" type="string" />
        <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" null="true" />
      ...
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

I get this:

```
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>services</Title>
  <FrameType>None</FrameType>
  <Description>Transforms XML data using XSL and shows the results.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>Left</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>0</PartOrder>
....
</WebPart>
```

Edit:
I tried to retype the web part, no success:

```
      <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
          <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XmlWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
          <properties>
            <property name="XMLLink" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Xml" type="string">mysite/test.xml</property>
            <property name="XSLLink" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Xml" type="string">mysite/test.xsl</property>
            <property name="Title" type ="String">services</property>
            <property name="FrameType" type ="String">None</property>
            <property name="Description" type ="String">Transforms XML data using XSL and shows the results.</property>
            <property name="IsIncluded" type ="bool">True</property>
            <property name="FrameState" type ="String">Normal</property>
            <property name="AllowRemove" type ="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AllowZoneChange" type ="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AllowMinimize" type ="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AllowConnect" type ="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AllowEdit" type ="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AllowHide" type ="bool">False</property>
            <property name="IsVisible" type ="bool">Frue</property>
          </properties>
        </data>
      </webPart>
```

I get an error saying 2 times, and I think, this is the xsl and the xml link, because I get the same when I remove all the other properties:

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested.

So, can someone please send a working example for the XML Web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for everyone who's interested, I found a workaround here:
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/869

Should I not interpret it 100% correctly, comments are welcome. 
Looks like Sharepoint has 2 type of webparts with 2 different schema's. To make the 2nd version working in the PnP template, the `<webParts>` tag should be omitted:

```
              <pnp:WebPart Title="Tasks" Row="2" Column="1">
                <pnp:Contents>
                 <WebParts> <!--- remove -->
                    <WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
                      <Title>services</Title>
                      <FrameType>None</FrameType>
                      <Description>Transforms XML data using XSL and shows the results.</Description>
                      <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  ...all other elements from the webpart...
                    </WebPart>
                  </WebParts> <!---  remove  -->
                </pnp:Contents>
              </pnp:WebPart>
```